# Does "NOT" apply to other logical operators in SQL?

Tags: sql

I was practicing SQL in w3resource.com" website and I had a problem understanding the solution of this exercise;

**link :** https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-boolean-operator-exercise-6.php

**the problem:**  Write an SQL statement to display either those orders which are not issued on date 2012-09-10 and issued by the salesman whose ID is 5005 and below or those orders which purchase amount is 1000.00 and below.

Sample table : orders

```
ord_no      purch_amt   ord_date    customer_id  salesman_id
----------  ----------  ----------  -----------  -----------
70001       150.5       2012-10-05  3005         5002
70009       270.65      2012-09-10  3001         5005
70002       65.26       2012-10-05  3002         5001
70004       110.5       2012-08-17  3009         5003
70007       948.5       2012-09-10  3005         5002
70005       2400.6      2012-07-27  3007         5001
70008       5760        2012-09-10  3002         5001
70010       1983.43     2012-10-10  3004         5006
70003       2480.4      2012-10-10  3009         5003
70012       250.45      2012-06-27  3008         5002
70011       75.29       2012-08-17  3003         5007
70013       3045.6      2012-04-25  3002         5001
```

**my solution:**

```
select * from orders where (ord_date <> '2012-09-10' and salesman_id <= '5005') or purch_amt <= '1000';
```

**their solution:**

```
SELECT * FROM  orders WHERE NOT ((ord_date ='2012-09-10'AND salesman_id > 5005) OR purch_amt > 1000.00);
```

**question:** in their solution the "NOT" statment apply on "OR" is that acceptable? and which solution is correct ?

**thank you**

Comment: The practice question is ambiguous, either answer could be a interpretation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT` takes one operand.  In this expression:

```
WHERE NOT ((ord_date ='2012-09-10'AND salesman_id > 5005) OR purch_amt > 1000.00);
```

The operand is the entire parenthesized expression.  You expression is not equivalent, but the above is equivalent to the following because `NOT (A OR B)` is equivalent to `(NOT A AND NOT B)` and `NOT (A AND B)` is equivalent to `(NOT A OR NOT B)`:

```
WHERE NOT (ord_date = '2012-09-10' AND salesman_id > 5005) AND
      NOT (purch_amt > 1000.00)

WHERE NOT (ord_date = '2012-09-10' AND salesman_id > 5005) AND
      purch_amt <= 1000.00

WHERE (NOT (ord_date = '2012-09-10') OR NOT (salesman_id > 5005)) AND
      purch_amt <= 1000.00

WHERE (ord_date <> '2012-09-10' OR salesman_id <= 5005) AND
      purch_amt <= 1000.00
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but does their answer is correct according to the text ?

Comment: @GuissousAllaeddine . . . The English is ambiguous because it is unclear what the `not` exactly refers to.  I think your interpretation is closer to the the English.  The `not` is a subclause of the `either`/`or`, so the `or` -- to may reading -- should not be negated.